# mac imager package on Studio using Mac 10.13.1( Hugh Sierra)

Tags: r, macos

I can't understand what doesn't work. It used to work that's why.
I'm installing the package imager on studio in order to transfer images into matrix but can't manage to use the package once installed. There are my lines and the error:

```
install.packages("imager")

library("imager")

error:
The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/xh/h1lfmzdj09n7_wxnk7rym4m00000gn/T//RtmpKNFNGS/downloaded_packages
> library(imager)
Erreur : package or namespace load failed for ‘imager’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 impossible de charger l'objet partagé '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/imager/libs/imager.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/imager/libs/imager.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/imager/libs/imager.so
```

Reason: image not found

Comment: Looks like you are missing X11. Was it working before a Mac OS update by any chance?

Comment: it was working before yes ( that's why I 'm quite lost right now)

Comment: I mean, has it stopped working after a Mac OS update? See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here's your solution

```
    sudo ln -s /opt/X11 /usr/X11
```

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208001/cant-compile-image-after-upgrading-to-os-x-yosemite